# How to use multitail with grep on each input file

Tags: grep, tail

My company's server runs Apache for MANY sites, but only has 1 (one) access.log and 1 (one) error.log.  One of the sites gets a lot of traffic, causing the logs to fly by on the screen fairly quickly, when using:

```
tail -f access.log
```

or

```
tail -f error.log
```

I want to use...

```
multitail access.log error.log
```

...but this won't work, as I won't even be able to see my seldom traffic.

However, I can grep out the sitename, and see only the access or error log for the site I am working on with a simple grep:

```
tail -f error.log | grep dev_db
```

This works, but only for one of the two logs at a time.

The thing is, I want to see both logs in the standard split-screen that multitail offers.
I wish to multitail the two files (access & error) but grep for specific lines containing the sitename.

How can I do this?  I've man`ed multitail, and I have seen the -E for regular expressions, but I don't think that would work (and if it would, then I don't know how to use it correctly.

If there is a way to do this, would you please use the "dev_db" in your response showing me how to do it?

--

--

*Please, and Thank You*

Answer (score 2):

You can run `-E` as described in the man page:

> -E     Use the next regular expression on the following files.

```
multitail -E dev_db file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I saw that and tried it, but I was not doing the regular expression correctly, I was being too complicated -E '/*jlee38*'  I am a complete noob at regular expressions, and don't really know what I'm doing.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay, so right now I am using this: "multitail -E jlee recdb_error_log recdb_ssl_access_log" but I also want to add a "deubg.log" to the list of files being multitailed, however it can't have the "jlee' restriction, as that isn't in the file.  Ideas?
Basically, I need to apply the restriction to the first 2 files, but not the 3rd.

Comment: Is it this:
multitail -E jlee recdb_error_log recdb_ssl_access_log -E '' /var/logs/debug.log